# @media (display-mode: standalone) not working after PWABuilder

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I have used PWABuilder.com to make my PWA into a native iOS app. However, in the native iOS app the CSS query `@media (display-mode: standalone)` does not detect when the app is standalone.

How would I fix this?